# Writing Unit Tests For TornadoFX

Tags: gradle, kotlin, tornadofx

I have a Gradle project written in Kotlin using the TornadoFX framework. I am new to all of these things. Does anyone know, or can point me to, some tutorials on how to write unit tests for this type of project? I am not sure of TornadoFX is supposed to have its own testing framework, or if gradle has one that I should be using.

Answer (score 1):

In case any people wander over to this page with the same question, here is the answer:

In my case, I used gradle to build this project. Therefore, I used gradle to run the tests. You write tests the same way you would in Java, like so

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.*  //this imports your assert methods

class TestCases{

   @Test
   fun testMethod(){
      //initialize expected value
      //calculate actual value
      assertEquals(actual, expected)
   }
}
```

The important parts are the import statements and the '@Test' tag. The important statements give you the functionality to run tests. The '@Test' tag is put above any method that you want to be run as a test.

Once you finish writing your tests, go to your preferred terminal and cd to the directory containing your project. Then run this command (I work in Windows so I use a .bat file):

```
./gradlew.bat test
```

That's all you need to run unit tests for your Kotlin project.

Comment: While this is the proper way to test a normal Java application, TornadoFX application is initially a JavaFX application and it needs extra care for testing since JavaFX uses its own thread and, in some cases, you need to do the testing headless. [testfx](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX) is a nice project dealing with this but I do not know if it is compatible with TornadoFX since it is initially a Java project.

Comment: @ErdinEray that should be fine. TornadoFX directly builds on top of JavaFX and Kotlin was built on JVM. *"[Pretty much all Java code can be used without any issues](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)"*. The only problem I could see is not having a matching JDK version between your dependencies.